# Having trouble implementing photon mapping

Tags: c++, raytracing

I'm currently working on a simple raytracer, and until now I've successfully implemented several features, like antialiasing, depth of field and soft shadows with area lights.
An image representing my work could be this one:

[image]
(there's no AA here)

The next step was adding reality to the render with some global illumination algorithm, so I decided to move to the photon mapping way, which seemed the easiest one.

To do so I read some papers I found on the web, such as this one:  http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348b-01/course8.pdf
which is very well written.

Now my program can shoot photons in the scene and store them after the first bounce (diffuse or specular), then scale the power of every single photon to LIGHT_POWER / PHOTON_AMOUNT.
A direct visualization of this is represented in these images, where I shot 1000k and 50k photons, each allowed to bounce 6 times, for a total of 5000k and 250k photons in the global map:

[image]

[image]

I thought the effect is right, so I moved to the next part, the one where the photons within a certain radius over the intersection point of the raytraced rays are used to calculate the indirect illumination.

In my raytracer I do as follows:

1. for each pixel I send a ray trough it to intersect the scene and calculate the direct illumination `(dot(N, L) * primitive.color * primitive.diffuseFactor * light.power)`, and the specular term;
2. Here is the tricky part: I look for the nearest photons which lie in a fixed radius disc around the point of intersection and sum the light produced by each one this way:

   for each photon within radius
         calculate light the same way as for direct lighting
            (dot(-photonDir, N) * primitive.color * photonColor)
         and sum everything up.
3. When every interesting photon has been processed and added its contribution to the final color I divide it by the area of the disc which defines the search area.

The problem is that doing so I don't get the desired result, in particular the ceiling is very dark compared to images I found on the web (I can't get how the ceiling can be as bright as the floor if the latter has an additional contribution from the direct lighting, and how it can be white if the photons on it are only red or green).

An image representing the problem is the following:

[image]

This has been rendered using 150k photons, with 4 bounces each, and the direct illumination has been divided by PI.

Also, if you know how I can remove those ugly artifacts from the corners, please tell me.

Comment: it looks pretty good to me. well done

Comment: Thanks but as you can see the ceiling, which is my main issue, is very very dark, and if I boost the indirect illumination the only thing that will happen is that the color bleeding will become more noticeable which is not what I want

Comment: It is to be expected that the ceiling is dark: it has no direct illumination. If you see images on the web in which the ceiling is not dark, it's due to some ambient light that has been added to it (i. e. you would even see the ceiling if there were no light sources whatsoever). Color bleeding is also not unrealistic, it's just that we humans are so adapted at ignoring colored light that we usually don't realize it. That's why you often see photon light being grayed out to match the rendered image to expectation rather than reality. The only real artifact are the bright lines at the corners.

Comment: Well, the ceiling should be brighter than this for sure, like in the real cornell box website: http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/online/box/compare.html
or in other images from the web: http://www.peterkutz.com/computergraphics/images/path_tracer/PhotonMapping.png
or from path traced rendering: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonash/MCPT/MCPT_Result/Boxes/Dutre_Final_2048_Hemisphere.bmp

Comment: You're really going to have to narrow it down. This question, while interesting and valid in some place, is _far_ too broad for a programming Q&A repository.

Comment: My question is: from what I wrote, are there any errors in my algorithm to produce what I described above? If there is anyone here with some experience in this branch of computer graphics maybe he could help me. I think I said all the possible to help you figure out the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you only take N photons within the search area (that is, if the search area has 1000 photons, do you take all 1000, or do you only take the first/nearest N (say, 100) photons)?

Comment: I take every photon within the search area, in your example all the 1000 photons.

Comment: Okay, good (you can use the first/nearest N photons if you want (which will give slightly sharper caustics), but you have to shrink the area you're dividing by if you do; but that's not required, and your method sounds right so far). Now, for your photon searching, do you use photons that only lie on the disk (with some radius R), or do you use all the photons within the volume of the sphere with radius R?

Comment: I take all the photons in the sphere of radius R but my photons are organized in a way in which I can take only the photons on the primitive hit by the ray

Comment: Ah, that's part of the problem, and is why the corders of your box look so dark. You should take all the photons within the sphere volume, even if they hit a different object. It causes some slight artifacts and bleeding, but that's a normal side-effect of using photon mapping (and is why some people use Monte Carlo path tracing for a single bounce of computing global illumination, and then use photon mapping for the global illumination in the path tracing bounce). The middle of your ceiling is probably dark from not using very many bounces in your photons. 6 is very few bounces.

Comment: High quality renders can use 100 or more bounces for photon mapping.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but increasing the final number of photons in the photon map will bright up also the other parts of the scene and maybe the one directly lit will become too much bright. Maybe i have to decrease the intensity of the photons after some bounces?

Comment: Here is a version of the image in the question with 1000k photons, 5 bounces and the same radius: http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4007/3KnBoF.png I thought that having more photons in the same space looked brighter, but it's only smoother. I really want to try with much more samples now...

Comment: Mmmm, I've rendered the same scene with 50k photons, 100 bounces, and the same search radius, I've made a global photon map which isn't related to any primitive and reduced the power of the lamp from about 1.9 to 1.0, and here's the result: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img912/6514/X3F51u.png
I think that it's somewhat better because there is less difference between the directly lit section and the penumbra section, but the ceiling is still so dark... maybe I'm using too few photons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, thanks a lot for all your help.

Second, I'm here to announce that after some trouble and after a period in which I didn't touch the code, I finally got it.

I haven't understood what I was doing wrong, maybe the algorithm to get a random direction within a hemisphere, maybe the photon gathering pass...
The point is that after reformatting a bit the code (and after implementing a final gathering step and a 2.2 gamma correction) I was able to render the following with 200k photons, 10 diffuse bounces, 20 samples for direct lighting and 100 samples of FG (taken in random - cosine weighted - direction).

[image: The final result]

I'm very happy with this since it looks almost the same as a reproduction of the scene in c4d path traced with V-Ray.

I still haven't clear what is the utility to store the photon's incident direction, ahahahahahahah, but it works, so it's ok.

Thank's again.

Comment: "what is the utility to store the photon incident direction"


It's used for any BRDFs more complicated than pure diffuse. Since you seem to be using a pure lambertian model, you don't need it.

Comment: Ooh, so the brdf should be evaluated also when a photon bounces? (To determine its intensity)

Comment: Yes, you should be importance sampling the BRDF on each bounce, as well as applying in in the gather step. It's simple for lambertian surfaces however.

Comment: Uhmm, I'm a little confused about this. How do you find the importance sampling algorithm for each brdf model?

Comment: That's a question worth several academic papers. Here's one of them: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ravir/papers/brdf/brdf.pdf